# Remove underline from TabItem header when tabitem is selected

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I want to underline the TabItem Header Title when Mousehover on header , and remove the Underline once it is selected. 
I have tried below code:

```
    <Style x:Key="N3EntityNavigationItemStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type Custom11:TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="White" Padding="5,2">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="CP" ContentSource="Header">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="CP" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding}"  TextDecorations="Underline"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But the tabitem header still remain underline after selecting the tab.

Comment: How did you declare and assign the `Style` element with this xaml code?

Comment: Try just moving your ismouseover trigger up to the top of the triggers collection.